# Center Text and SVG Elements Vertically with No Padding and Text Aligned

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to format a series of labels and svg elements; however, I cannot seem to get the alignment correct. I have searched various css alignment strategies and have come up empty handed so far. The code below produces a label and a box with text in the center. I would like the label text and the text in the box to be centered vertically to the same line. Currently they are offset a bit. I also notice that the margin around the two elements is not consistent (the space between the border and the top is smaller than between the border and the bottom), which may be causing some of the misalignment. Ideally, I would like to eliminate all margin/padding around the elements as well as center them properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        h1{
            margin-right: 10px;
            font-size:1.5em;
        }
        #parent{
            border:1px solid black; 
            display: flex; 
            justify-content: left; 
            align-items: center;
        }
        div{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        svg{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <h1>
            Label
        </h1>
        <div>
            <svg width="50" height="50">
                <g>
                    <rect height="50" width="50" x="0" y="0" fill="#A2E074" rx="5" ry="5"/>
                    <text text-anchor="middle" style="alignment-baseline: central; fill: #666;" x="25" y="25">
                        SVG
                    </text>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center text inside svg with these:

1.Set the position of the text to the absolute center of the element in which you want to center it:
        If it's the parent, you could just do x="50%" y ="50%".
        If it's another element, x would be the x of that element + half its width (and similar for y but with the height).

2.Use the text-anchor property to center the text horizontally with the value middle:

```
    middle

    The rendered characters are aligned such that the geometric middle of the resulting rendered text is at the initial current text position.
```

3.Use the alignment-baseline property to center the text vertically with the value middle (or depending on how you want it to look like, you may want to do central)

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
        <h1>
            Label
        </h1>
        <div>
            <svg width="300" height="300">
                <g>
                    <rect height="300" width="300"  fill="#A2E074" rx="5" ry="5"/> 
                    <text text-anchor="middle"  style="alignment-baseline: middle; fill: #666;" x="50%" y="50%">
                        SVG
                    </text>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I may not have been very clear in my question. My apologies. Your solution centers the text in the SVG; however, the label and the SVG text are not aligned horizontally. This becomes apparent if you shrink the width and height of the svg element and rect to something lower (e.g. 50). I would like them to both be centered vertically, but on the same horizontal line.